# Noisy output of Hall current sensor

Tags: sensor, noise, hall-effect, current-sensor

I am designing a buck converter with a switching frequency of 200 kHz. I measure the current using a Hall-sensor, the [ACS730KLCTR-20AB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynxo9.png).

The implementation is the following:
[image]

I think the routing is also good.

When I watch the output of the sensor (yellow) and its power supply (blue) with a scope I see a far from nice triangle signal:

[image]

I have noise with different frequencies.

I know the bandwidth of the ACS730 is "only" 1 MHz and my signal is 200 kHz, so maybe there is some Shannon stuff here. I haven't done this before so I don't know what I should expect!

Comment: _"I think the routing is also good."_ Please show!

Comment: I can't, it is proprietary, but my question was more, with the best conditions (routing, EMI environment,..), should I have a more triangular shape ?

Comment: Understandable. Can you place a current probe with ideally more bandwidth to have something to compare it with? Best guess is that layout has a bigger influence than you expect. Just for a test, does it change at all if you add more and better (i.e. smaller than 1206) capacitors for decoupling?

Comment: Yes, with a current probe (20MHz BW), the signal is perfectly triangular ! I will try the cap !

Comment: In that case, it's either layout + decoupling related to the ACS730 or less probable, internal noise to it. What's your stackup? How does Vcc look when your probe it?

Comment: More decoupling with smaller (less ESR) capacitors! Stronger ground!

Comment: Okay, Will try ! Thanks !